# mvc enum viewmodel binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to bind an enum from a model to viewmodel. I understand this can be done via a select list conversion approach but there is no user input for this input. Do I have to change it to select list to use it in viewmodel?

The Model:

```
 public enum JobStatus
{
    Uncomplete=1, Complete=2
}


public class Job
{
public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The view model:

```
 public class JobDetailsVM

{
  public JobStatus JobStatus { get; set; }
}
```

The controller:

```
 var job = db.Jobs.Find(id);

        var JobDetails = new JobDetailsVM
        {
            IncidentID = job.IncidentID,
            ActionID = job.ActionID,
            JobStatus = job.JobStatus,
            CheckDone = job.CheckDone,
```

On:

```
  JobStatus = job.JobStatus,
```

I get the following error: Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'WomsUICF.Models.JobStatus' to 'WomsUICF.Models.ViewModels.JobStatus'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have defined the same enum in two places. Is it possible to eliminate one of them? If not, you should be able to do this assignment via a cast:

```
JobStatus = (WomsUICF.Models.ViewModels.JobStatus)job.JobStatus
```

Comment: Yep there both required..Uh... I really hope the solution wasn't this simple! It seems like what I am looking for.Let me see how it builds...

Comment: Hi this works perfectly. Just wondering if there anything I should know. the cast refers to the view model not domain, is that ok?